# Make the main label variable and base it on my conditioning variable

Tags: r, lattice

I am generating a xyplot conditioned on a certain variable. I do not want the conditioning variable to be visible in the panel label, But I would like for it to be visible as a part of the main label. I would like to add a variable to the main so that the main on each page (my layout is c(1,1)) has a different text based on my conditioning variable. Here is the example of my code.

```
xyplot(counts ~ time|conditioningvariable,
data = test.df,
pch=".",cex=1.5,
ylab="Counts (n)",
xlab="Time (sec)",
main=paste("Count By Time for ",conditioningvariable,sep=" "),
layout=c(1,1),scales=list(relation="free"),
strip=FALSE)
```

I know I would have to use the panel function if I want to have this text change per panel, but I not sure how I would go about it. I know this might be extremely simple. Would be really thankful for a solution.

Comment: Can't test without some sample data, but try wrapping `conditioningvariable` in `deparse(substitute())`. Also, I am just assuming to know what you are getting vs what you want.

Comment: @rawr I am actually getting an error `object 'conditioningvariable' not found` instead of having different panels with different main titles. Does that help?

Comment: You should look at the all questions you have asked. Give checkmarks to the correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
... , 
main = substitute(expression(Count~By~Time~'for'~X), list(X=conditioningvariable) ),
... ,
strip = strip.custom(strip.levels=c(FALSE,FALSE), strip.names=c(FALSE,FALSE)), 
... ,
```

Tested solutions rather than guesses offered when reproducible data is provided.

That would not work unless there were also an object named `conditioningvariable` in the global environment. It would not recover the value from the xyplot call. I played around with the iris dataset and the examples in the help pages and found that the above guess would not succeed. The conditioning levels are stored in the result of `xyplot` as `$condlevel` [as documented here](http://markmail.org/message/akfmyjk7py3tai7x?q=list%3aorg.r-project.r-help%20xyplot%20get%20name%20of%20conditioning%20variable). (Turns out my memory was failing me since I was part of that exchange.) So a 2 step process succeeds:

```
X <- xyplot(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width | Species, iris,
           main = substitute(expression(Count~By~Time~'for'~X), list(X='Species') ) )

xyplot(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width | Species, iris, 
       main = substitute(expression(Count~By~Time~'for'~X), list(X=names(X$condlevel)) )
       )
```

It also turns out that you can suppress the levels or the conditioning names with single FALSE values.

This will print a "title" that doesn't look like a strip with varying condition levels per page:

```
X <- xyplot(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width | Species, iris,
pch=".",cex=1.5,
ylab="Counts (n)",
xlab="Time (sec)", layout=c(1,1,3) ,
scales=list(relation="free"),
strip=function(...){ ltext(.5,.5,paste("Count By Time for ", levels(iris$Species)[panel.number() ]))})
print(X)
```

For more space at the top use `main="\n"` and `ltext(.5, 1,` ...)`.

Comment: I tried the above code with the Iris data. But the main title only has _Count By Time for Species_ While it does not actually say _Count By Time for setosa_ or _Count By Time for versicolor_ . Anything went amiss?

Comment: You didn't actually say what you wanted. It wouldn't really be appropriate to have the main title say either setosa or versicolor would it? Are you confusing the "main" title with the strip text above each panel? You also might consider seeing if the questions that you have not accepted have valid answers.

Comment: apologies if you could not gather it earlier. What I am doing is making one panel per page, and not have strip labels for each panel. But have the text that is supposed to go in each strip label instead be a part of the main title. Again, apologies.